# Maximizing (ordering) version number elements in Neo4j database

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, jqassistant

I have used jQAssistant to fill a Neo4j database with information about java artifacts.

Now I want to find the latest version of some artifact fulfilling some conditions. At first glance, I could use `max(a.version)` on the version property of an artifact. But artifact versions are not ordered by the usual String order, but actually 1.10.0 is a later version than 1.2.0.

How could I implement or use a custom ordering scheme like the one described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could break your version number string down into 3 separate attributes (major, minor, point) and keep each of those as an integer.

Consider the following data

```
create (n:Node {name: 'first',version: '1.2.0', ver_major: 1, ver_minor: 2, ver_point: 0})
create (n:Node {name: 'second',version: '1.10.0', ver_major: 1, ver_minor: 10, ver_point: 0})
```

As you have see if you search for and order by version they are returned in alphabetical order.

```
match (n:Node) 
return n.name, n.version 
order by n.version
```

One alternative would be to persist the version numbers in separate attributes as integers.

```
match (n:Node) 
return n.name, n.version 
order by n.ver_major, n.ver_minor, n.ver_point
```

Another alternative would be to split the string into component versions and order on those. `toInt` is required though otherwise the values will still be ordered as strings.

```
match (n:Node) 
return n.name
, n.version
, toInt(split(n.version,'.')[0]) as major
, toInt(split(n.version,'.')[1]) as minor
, toInt(split(n.version,'.')[2]) as point
order by major, minor, point
```

Answer (score 2):

How about that for version numbers (major, minor and patch) to have their nodes? Something like that:

```
// Major
MERGE (M0:Semver:Major {v: 0}) 
MERGE (M1:Semver:Major {v: 1})
// Minor
MERGE (Mi0: Semver:Minor {v: 0 }) 
MERGE (Mi2: Semver:Minor {v: 2 }) 
MERGE (Mi10:Semver:Minor {v: 10})
// Patch
MERGE (P0:Semver:Patch {v:0}) 
MERGE (P2:Semver:Patch {v:2})

// Artifacts
MERGE (A1:Artifact {name:'Artifact 13afd'})
MERGE (A2:Artifact {name:'Artifact asdfk'})
MERGE (A3:Artifact {name:'Artifact 09sd2'})
MERGE (A4:Artifact {name:'Artifact skw30'})

// Versioning
MERGE (A1)-[:semver]->(M0) MERGE (A1)-[:semver]->(Mi0 ) MERGE (A1)-[:semver]->(P0)
MERGE (A2)-[:semver]->(M0) MERGE (A2)-[:semver]->(Mi0 ) MERGE (A2)-[:semver]->(P2)
MERGE (A3)-[:semver]->(M1) MERGE (A3)-[:semver]->(Mi2 ) MERGE (A3)-[:semver]->(P0)
MERGE (A4)-[:semver]->(M1) MERGE (A4)-[:semver]->(Mi10) MERGE (A4)-[:semver]->(P0)

RETURN *;
```

[image]

And the desired query:

```
MATCH  (A:Artifact)-[:semver]->(Mj:Semver:Major),
       (A         )-[:semver]->(Mi:Semver:Minor),
       (A         )-[:semver]->(Pt:Semver:Patch)
RETURN A.name,  Mj.v,     Mi.v,     Pt.v
       ORDER BY Mj.v asc, Mi.v asc, Pt.v asc
```